# AzCopy migration unknown command /source error

Tags: azure, migration, data-migration

```
AzCopy /Source:https://sourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1
/Dest:https://destaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2
/SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /S
```

After using this script to migrate data from one container to another it shows an error:

> unknown command "/source:https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxx" for
>   "azcopy"

while the rest of the commands (copy, sync) are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your command works fine on my end. Try to remove and [reinstall AzCopy](https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy), because nothing is wrong with your command.

Comment: It still wont work. Shows the same error.

Comment: Did you try another device? Or try to run AzCopy ad administrator.

Comment: I tried on other devices as well, i think i am repeating same mistake everywhere.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42257

which version you are using ?

Comment: 8.1.0. Downloaded from the link I provided earlier. Is it solved? You said that the case can be closed on the github page.

Comment: Yes, its solved. They changed the syntax for the latest version(10.3.1). It will work in version 8 but not in 10.3.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the old azcopy.... not easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is Microsoft have created a totally new program with a completely different syntax and called it AzCopy.  There's an old syntax and there's the AzCopy v10+ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AzCopy` syntax is incorrect. Take a look at [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs) link

**Copy a container to another storage account**

Syntax

```
azcopy copy 'https://<source-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>?<SAS-token>' 'https://<destination-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>' --recursive
```

Example

```
azcopy copy 'https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-07-04T05:30:08Z&st=2019-07-03T21:30:08Z&spr=https&sig=CAfhgnc9gdGktvB=ska7bAiqIddM845yiyFwdMH481QA8%3D' 'https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer' --recursive
```

Comment: This works, but it's just a new feature of AzCopy and so not the right answer to Amit.

Comment: That's what i was thinking, the copy command and the command that i mentioned are different.